# Why is Python3 decode/encode duplicating characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, base64

I am trying to check the subject of emails in foreign languages for automatic tests.  I was having issues with encoding so I decided to try and write something that handles the encoding of the subject.  In this case it's given to me in base64.  Converting this to utf-8 and then decoding it produces this strange double character problem.  Here is some code I used to test this:

```
import base64

ja_str = "こんにちは"

    encoded_js = base64.b64encode(ja_str.encode())
    print (encoded_js)

    print(base64.b64decode(encoded_js).decode())
```

The result of the above is:

```
b'44GT44KT44Gr44Gh44Gv'
ここんんににちちはは
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. your second `print` gives me `こんにちは`

Comment: This seems to be a windows issue as I can't repeat it on Mac or Ubuntu.  But here is what I was seeing: https://imgur.com/a/R2FBJ  Note that the initial Japanese string is pasted in.  I'm going to go ahead as this seems to just be a GUI issues as opposed to python doing it wrong.

Comment: Um, you pretty clearly do `ja_string = "ここんんににちちはは"` in that image... so do you mean you copied `"こんにちは"` then pasted it into your terminal emulator and got `ja_string = "ここんんににちちはは"`?

Comment: Correct, I copy こんにちは and I get ここににちちはは

Comment: So that *is* weird, and might be worth it's own question. But it looks like it is related to whatever terminal emulator you are using... `cmd` in windows?

Comment: I'm using ConEmu currently and they have a github ticket from over a year ago about the issue but it's closed.  I'll have to look into it more.  Thanks for your help.